# making images all the same size with css rule - styles not changing image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get all my images the same size, with a little bit of padding/space between each image. The code that I am using doesn't seem to be working, the images stay their original size (and are all different sizes).

CSS

```
.gallery {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 5%;
}
```

HTML

```
<form id="Form1" method="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">       
    <label>
        <input type="text" id="albumname" name="albumname" class="form-control" placeholder="Album Name" required autofocus>
    </label>

    <div class="input-group">
        <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
            <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Choose Files...
        </label>
        <input id="file-upload" type="file" multiple/>          
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin-upload" type="submit">Upload</button>
    </div>  

    <div class="gallery"></div>
</form>
```

Does anyone know the problem? It is for previewing a number of images before uploading them.

Comment: "Not working" is not something anyone can help with

Comment: You must tell us the exact problem, what is happening with the images

Comment: Could you please include the html in the question?

Comment: @Abhijit I added the html

Comment: @Guilherme I updated the question, the images are staying their original size once I add them

Comment: Your css applies to elements with class `gallery`, not whatever images you put inside.

Comment: @csmckelvey Ooh right, how do I add the css to the images inside the div?

Comment: Instead of `.gallery` use something like `img { ... }` or give all the images the same class or something like that.

Comment: The css style called “gallery” sets height width for probably the containing div. not on images

Answer (score 2):

In your CSS you have a class called `.gallery`, this however is referring to a div and not to an image. That's why all your images are still in their original resolution. Adding the following snippet to your CSS will make all images within the div 100px x 100px.

```
.gallery img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Major flaw with this: it absolutely positively depends on all images having a perfect 1:1 ratio.  Otherwise, it will stretch / skew.  A preferred alternative is to do something like `width: 100px; height: auto;` or similar.

Comment: @cale_b that's indeed correct. However I noticed that the OP was using this ratio in his question and that's why I assumed all the images do have a perfect ratio.

Comment: Indeed, you are right.  Just worth pointing it out, since OP clearly is somewhat new, and might not understand that is going to happen.

Comment: when ever I use this code the images no longer show up once I have selected them from the file path. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: @cs123445 - you've got to learn to post your code. What does your image markup look like? What does the path look like? Are you sure the image is there?

Comment: @cale_b Sorry I am new to this, this is a fiddle with all my code in it. The image is definitely there because it shows up in the elements. When I hover over each image link in the developer tools each image seems to be the same size as there is a faded blue box that appears in the html, but they are not physically appearing so don't know for definite. https://jsfiddle.net/p3p6o8y0/

Comment: Keep it simple, @cs123445 - test the CSS / image issue _without a file upload_.  You may be confusing the problem, since I'm unsure if jsFiddle actually uploads / stores file uploads.  Also, you have the gallery images set to 10px x 10px, which is microscopic - don't you mean 100px x 100px?

Comment: I got it sorted, I was just using 10px x 10px as an example. It is at a reasonable size now. Thanks anyway